# Append Row To An HTML File

Tags: jsoup, java

I have a HTML file that contains a table with a variable amount of row. I'd like to be able to open that file, select the table, append a row (the amount of columns is fixed), and write this back to file file. I'm not quire sure how to proceed.

UPDATED: Here's a simplified but HTML-valid file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Light Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>CTS QA Test Report</h1>
        <p id="suiteintrotext"></p>
        <h1>Summary</h1>
        <table class="table" id="summarytable">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Test Name</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Start/End time (dur.)</th>
                <th>Avg. CPU%</th>
                <th>Pass</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>two</td>
                <td>three</td>
                <td>four</td>
                <td>five</td>
                <td>six</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The second row is there to get some data for the step-by-step troubleshooting in Eclipse

This is as far as I managed to go in Java:

```
public void appendRow() throws ParserConfigurationException{
    File source = new File(this.Path);
    Document report = null;
    try {
        report = Jsoup.parse(source, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open ["+source.getAbsolutePath()+"] for parsing!");
    }
    Elements table = report.select("#summarytable");
    // Create row and td elements add append?       
}
```

My problem at this point is how to add a row, which itself should have more elements (the cells/columns). The problem right after that point would be how to save this in the HTML file?

Comment: "I have a HTML fail" hehehehe

Comment: There's an amusing spelling mistake in the first sentence of your question

Comment: Aah, sorry, I didn't get that :) Corrected!

Comment: Is a table when missing tbody and thead, valid? I honestly don't know. Not trying to be a wiseass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        File source = new File(this.Path);
        Document report = null;
        try {
            report = Jsoup.parse(source, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open ["+source.getAbsolutePath()+"] for parsing!");
        }
        Elements dom = report.children();

        dom.select("#summarytable tbody").append("<tr><td>onempla</td><td>twompla</td><td>threempla</td><td>fourmpla</td><td>fivempla</td><td>sixmpla</td></tr>");

        if(!source.canWrite()) System.out.println("Can't write this file!") //Just check if the file is writable or not

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(source));
        bw.write(dom.toString()); //toString will give all the elements as a big string
        bw.close();  //Close to apply the changes
```

Comment: This works to write a table, but the problem is it overwrites the rest of the HTML file (anything before or after the table, for instance the <div> in the above example, and even the <table> element)

Comment: Check my update. Sorry for the late response but for some reason I didn't see a notification.

Comment: Jsoup will validate the html and will add some tags (like html, body, tbody etc) that should be there. I believe that's not a problem.

Comment: HTML is valid, I didn't posted a full version of it. I updated the question. Your updated code works perfectly, thanks a lot :) There's only a little mistake, it should be bw.write(dom.toString()) not "table.toString()" :) Please edit and I'll mark as the solution! Thanks a lot!